# How to return value from Swift closure?

Tags: ios, swift, return, closures

I'm new at swift closures.
I have this code and i can't extract the values from the forloop into the arrays outside the closure.

Sorry about this question but i have already searched stackflow but without success in this specific case.

Thanks in advance.

```
var namesArray: [String] = []
var imagesArray: [String] = []
var timesArray: [String] = []
var placesArray: [String] = []

func getData(){
    //DATA SOURCE
    // Create request for user's Facebook data
    let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: cmp.pageId, parameters: ["fields": "events"])

    // Send request to Facebook
    request.startWithCompletionHandler {

        (connection, result, error) in

        if error != nil {
            // Some error checking here
            print(error.debugDescription)
        } else
            if let pageData = result["events"] {
                print(result["events"]!!["data"]!![0]["name"])
                if let eventDetails = pageData!["data"] {

                    // EVENT DETAILS FETCH
                    for var i = 0; i < eventDetails!.count; i++
                    {
                        let fetchedEventName = eventDetails![i]["name"] as? String!
                        let fetchedEventTime = eventDetails![i]["start_time"] as? String!

                        if eventDetails?[i]["place"]??["name"] != nil {
                            if let fetchedEventPlace = eventDetails?[i]["place"]??["name"] {
                                self.placesArray.append(fetchedEventPlace! as! String)
                            }
                        } else {
                            self.placesArray.append("Lisbon")
                        }
                        self.namesArray.append(fetchedEventName!)
                        self.timesArray.append(fetchedEventTime!)
                    }
                    print("Name of event: \(self.namesArray)")
                }
            } else {
                print("Error.")
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    getData()
}
```

EDIT: I want to show the fetched result into a tableview that's already set.
Heres the tableview code.

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("previewCell") as? PreviewCell {

        var img: UIImage!

        let url = NSURL(string: imagesArray[indexPath.row])!
        if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url){
            img = UIImage(data: data)
        } else {
            img = UIImage(named: "ant")
        }

        cell.configureCell(img, title: namesArray[indexPath.row], time: timesArray[indexPath.row], place: placesArray[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    } else {
        return PreviewCell()
    }
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return namesArray.count
}

func addNewEvent(name: String, image: String, time: String, place: String)
{
    namesArray.append(name)
    imagesArray.append(image)
    timesArray.append(time)
    placesArray.append(place)
}
```

Comment: You don't. You put the logic into the closure and then call `reloadData`. That is it. The closure is executed asynchronously  and might be called seconds after the program let the `getData` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already getting the number in to the arrays so what you need to do is just reload the tableview after the for loop.

```
//end of for-loop
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

The reason for this is the asynchronous execution of the `request.startWithCompletionHandler`. The code inside that block will most likely execute after your tableView already loaded and it therefor needs a reload after the data has been fetched

Comment: Thank you Moriya!
Your answer did the trick.

Thanks to luk2302 also.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you need to return data from closure you can define completion on your getData() method like this

```
func getData(completion:([DataType]) -> Void) {
    //process data
    let dataArray:DataType = []
    completion(dataArray)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    getData { (completionData) -> Void in
        // process returned data 
    }
}
```

Hope this helps